# Powershell commend result into batch script variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to get time stamp in seconds in a batch script.

I am trying to run powershell command and put the result into a variable.

That's what I try:

```
FOR /F %%t IN (' PowerShell -Command "(Get-Date -UFormat %s -Millisecond 0).ToString()" ') DO SET tmsmp=%%t
```

When I run `PowerShell -Command "(Get-Date -UFormat %s -Millisecond 0).ToString()"` it works fine.

When I run:

```
FOR /F %t IN (' PowerShell -Command "(Get-Date -UFormat %s -Millisecond 0).ToString()" ') DO SET tmsmp=%t
```

From command line I get 
`SET tmsmp=1553591432` in the prompt. But Inside the script I don't get the result and `%tmsmp%` remains empty.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your major issue is that **`%`** is a special character in a batch file, this means that PowerShell's **`%s`** should be escaped with an additional **`%`**, i.e. **`%%s`**

That said, I would prefer to simplify the command using the batch method of obtaining a filename without extension, as it splits off everything from and including the last period.

```bat
For /F %%t In ('PowerShell Get-Date -UFormat %%s') Do Set "tsmp=%%~nt"
```

Comment: Thank you. Just fount the answer. Do you perhaps know how to multiple it by 1000 now?

Comment: Well unless I'm misunderstanding something, to multiply an integer by `1000`, you'd simply suffix three `0`'s, `For /F %%t In ('PowerShell Get-Date -UFormat %%s') Do Set "tsmp=%%~nt000"`.

Comment: LOL, just did exactly that. Thanks alot.